# showing thumbnail before image upload in html using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, image, multipartform-data

i have a form designed in html, the form has 2 image uploads, i am trying to show thumbnail to the user before he submits the form, I have the following code:

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#imaged')
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#imageds')
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <img id="imaged" style="width:150px; height: 150px; border-radius:50%;" src="" alt="image">
  <input onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" name="" class="form-control" style="margin-top:2%;">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <img style="width:150px; height: 150px; border-radius:50%;" src="" alt="image">
  <input id="imageds" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" name="" class="form-control" style="margin-top:2%;">
</div>
```

however this is not showing the image as thumbnail instead its just showing the image name near the choose file button. can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot closing curly bracket in your readURL()
2. you misplaced id **imageds** to input tag instead of image tag

so final code will be like

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#imaged')
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#imageds')
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <img id="imaged" style="width:150px; height: 150px; border-radius:50%;" src="" alt="image">
    <input onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" name="" class="form-control" style="margin-top:2%;">
</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img id="imageds" style="width:150px; height: 150px; border-radius:50%;" src="" alt="image">
  <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" name="" class="form-control" style="margin-top:2%;">
</div>
```

Comment: bro your code is working here, but when I upload it to my website its not, can I place the can link and javascript anywhere in the page or is there any specific place like header it footer?

Comment: make sure you include jQuery CDN  , like in the answer, and this cdn you can include inside your head tag or at the end of your body tag before the body tag close (</body>) and whole JS code can be place in separate .js file (that file should get include in your html file) or inside <head> tag you can put <script>YOUR JS CODE</script>